Input audio driver not found (AMD Audio Device)
HP Victus Fb1002Ax laptops input mic not showing in ubuntu. In windows the driver name is showing as AMD Audio Device. Is there any driver available for this device

You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; and if using a LTS release which kernel stack you're using (changing kernel stack can cause different kernel modules/drivers to be used/available)
